# Where is AJP connector Ubuntu 16, Tomcat 8?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Hi I need to configure AJP connector, which I cannot find.
My ubuntu server is running Apache 2 and I need to redirect all the requests to Tomcat8 server. I am a new in this stuff and kinda struggling to find the proper stuff.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei,

I believe you need to make sure that you have **mod_jk** installed and configured for your Apache server, further, you have to explicitly enable this feature in the tomcat `server.xml` file. Find exact location where your tomcat is located, usually it is called **$CATALINA_BASE**. In my case it is located `/var/lib/tomcat_vesion>/`.

Once you're in the directory open ./conf/server.xml file and make sure the `ajp-connector` is not disabled, namely, there is no **#** symbol in front of this line:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I suggest you to read this article (https://www.creang.com/howtoforge/howto_set_up_tomcat_8_with_apache_2_4_and_mod_jk_on_ubuntu/) and try to spend more time with documentation.

Cheers!